# How to write text on image with overlay effect in c#

Tags: c#, image, text, graphics, overlay

I want to write text over an image with an overlay blending effect. Not a simple transparency, but mix the pixels of the image with the color of text.

I have this function which writes the text over the image, but this uses just a simple transparency.

```
grPhoto.DrawString(strText,        //string of text
    crFont,                            //font
    semiTransBrush,                    //Brush
    new PointF(xCenterOfImg,yPosFromBottom),  //Position
    StrFormat);                               //Text alignment
```

Comment: What effect are you looking for? Transparency also matches 'mix the pixels of the image with color of text'.

Comment: I want an effect like in photoshop overlay blending mode. The base color is not replaced but is mixed with the blend color to reflect the lightness or darkness of the original color.

Comment: Can you show overlay effect with the help of some image.

Comment: Overlay combines Multiply and Screen blend modes. Light parts of the picture become lighter and dark parts become darker. An overlay with the same picture looks like an S-curve.
Formula: Result Color = if (Bottom Color < 128) then (2 * Top Color * Bottom Color / 255) else (255 - 2 * (255 - Top Color) * (255 - Bottom Color) / 255)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [formula that Photoshop](http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/articles/blendmodes/overlay.htm) uses to calculate pixel values when using overlay blending. You may have to calculate each pixel during the blending yourself - I don't believe GDI+ has such specific support for blending. (I may be wrong, it's been a while since I used GDI+.)

Paint.NET uses a similar algorithm for its overlay blending implementation - Reflector may be able to give you ideas.

Comment: ok, but how can I make this with my text in a simpler way? paint.net uses complex layers and filters it's too complicated for what I need.

Comment: @MarioM you'll have to do the same. First render your text onto a transparent bitmap and then blend this bitmap onto your original bitmap. During this blending process, your code will have to loop through all pixels of your top layer (text bitmap) and calculate the final pixel by applying the formula to pixels in the text bitmap and the original bitmap. Whatever is the result for a given pixel is your output pixel at that position. This article may be useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

Comment: @MarioM I don't believe there's a simpler way if you want that particular blending effect. You may be able to tweak your text color that simple transparency works for you.

Comment: I tought that I can make a brush to create this effect. :(

Comment: The problem with simple transparency is that when I write the text over a gray image, the text it's almost invisible and on a black image, the text is very bright.

Comment: @MarioM a brush simply represents a colored area - you can make the color transparent but it still represents that color. What you want is an entirely different effect where the output color depends on more than its own transparency.